# stop AsyncTask from restarting HTTPPOST

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask to perform transactions, anytime the user has no sufficient balance it starts the process from begining instead of just telling telling the user that you have insufficient balance, it tells the user that and tries again, continues like this till i have to delete app to make it stop

```
    class HttpGetAsyncTaskFirst extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ObscuredSharedPreferences serve = ObscuredSharedPreferences.getPrefs(PayService.this, "Serve", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String merchantId = serve.getString("MerchantId", null);
    String encryptedToken = serve.getString("EncryptedToken", null);
    String encryptedCustId = serve.getString("EncryptedCustId", null);
    String encryptedCurrency = serve.getString("EncryptedCurrency", null);
    String encryptedAmount = serve.getString("EncryptedAmount", null);
    String encryptedNarration = serve.getString("EncryptedNarration", null);

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            String paramMerchantId = merchantId;
            String paramEncryptedToken = encryptedToken;
            String paramEncryptedCustId = encryptedCustId;
            String paramEncryptedCurrency = encryptedCurrency;
            String paramEncryptedAmount = encryptedAmount;
            String paramEncryptedNarration = encryptedNarration;

            String result = null;
            String JsonResponse = null;

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(Config.PAY_URL_RENEW);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                // is output buffer writter
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("merchantid", paramMerchantId);
                jsonParam.put("amount", paramEncryptedAmount);
                jsonParam.put("currency", paramEncryptedCurrency);
                jsonParam.put("chargetoken", paramEncryptedToken);
                jsonParam.put("narration", paramEncryptedNarration);
                jsonParam.put("custid", paramEncryptedCustId);


            //set headers and method
                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new  OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                System.out.println("input" + jsonParam.toString());

           // json data
                writer.close();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                System.out.println("input" + inputStream );
          //input stream
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                JsonResponse = buffer.toString();
                System.out.println("Response" + JsonResponse);
              //response data

                return JsonResponse;




            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {

                    }
                }
            }
            return null;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ObscuredSharedPreferences pref = ObscuredSharedPreferences.getPrefs(PayService.this, "MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            final String userName = pref.getString("Username", null);
            final String email = pref.getString("Email", null);
            final String name = pref.getString("Name", null);
            String space=" ";
            String breaking = "\n";
            final String greet = getString(R.string.hi)+space+name+breaking+breaking;
            final String first = getString(R.string.first);
            final String insufficient = getString(R.string.insufficient);
            final String noReason = getString(R.string.no_reason);

            final ObscuredSharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            Firebase pay = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
            JSONObject ResponseObject = null;
            String str = null;
            String token = null;
            String message= null;
            String reference= null;
            try {
                ResponseObject = new JSONObject(result);
                str = ResponseObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("responsecode");
                token = ResponseObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("responsetoken");
                message= ResponseObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("responsemessage");
                reference= ResponseObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("transactionreference");


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if ("00".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                String body = greet+first+reference;
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
                Date resultdate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
                String dateInString = sdf.format(resultdate);
                System.out.println("String date:"+dateInString);

                Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                update.put(userName + "/subscription",Config.SUB_YES);
                update.put(userName + "/renewSub", Config.RENEW_YES);
                update.put(userName + "/activeCard",Config.CARD_ACTIVE);
                update.put(userName + "/lastSubscription", currentDateAndTime);
                update.put(userName + "/endSubscription", dateInString);
                update.put(userName + "/serviceRun",currentDateAndTime);
                pay.updateChildren(update);
                editor.remove("Subscription");
                editor.remove("Renew");
                editor.remove("ActiveCard");
                editor.putString("Subscription", Config.SUB_YES);
                editor.putString("Renew", Config.RENEW_YES);
                editor.putString("ActiveCard", Config.CARD_ACTIVE);
                editor.apply();

                AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
                        ObscuredSharedPreferences serve = ObscuredSharedPreferences.getPrefs(PayService.this, "Serve", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        ObscuredSharedPreferences.Editor serveEdit = serve.edit();
                        serveEdit.clear();
                        serveEdit.apply();

                Mail.connectWithHttpGetEmail(email, body);

            }else if("5".equalsIgnoreCase(str)){
                String body = greet+insufficient;
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                update.put(userName + "/subscription", Config.SUB_NO);
                update.put(userName + "/serviceRun",currentDateAndTime);
                pay.updateChildren(update);
                editor.remove("Subscription");
                editor.putString("Subscription", Config.SUB_NO);
                editor.apply();
                Mail.connectWithHttpGetEmail(email, body);
                AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);
                        ObscuredSharedPreferences serve = ObscuredSharedPreferences.getPrefs(PayService.this, "Serve", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        ObscuredSharedPreferences.Editor serveEdit = serve.edit();
                        serveEdit.clear();
                        serveEdit.apply();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                String body = greet+noReason;
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                update.put(userName + "/subscription", Config.SUB_NO);
                update.put(userName + "/serviceRun",currentDateAndTime);
                pay.updateChildren(update);
                editor.remove("Subscription");
                editor.putString("Subscription", Config.SUB_NO);
                editor.apply();
                Mail.connectWithHttpGetEmail(email, body);
                AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                manager.cancel(pendingIntent);

                manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);
                        ObscuredSharedPreferences serve = ObscuredSharedPreferences.getPrefs(PayService.this, "Serve", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        ObscuredSharedPreferences.Editor serveEdit = serve.edit();
                        serveEdit.clear();
                        serveEdit.apply();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @selbie i don't want it to restart the httpost anytime the result is insufficient funds, its restarts any time it passes through the the first else if. and keeps on going till i delete the app

Comment: From what you are suggesting, your AsyncTask object is getting repeatedly scheduled.  (Because there's no retry logic in the code you posted).  What code path calls the `execute()` method on your `HttpGetAsyncTaskFirst` class instance?  Set a breakpoint there, because that's where the repeated call is likely being made.

Comment: @selbie seen where it is coming from, it comes from where i try to update firebase in the second else if, figuring a new way on how to save the data